# Identifying Asymptotes of a Hyperbola

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

[basic hyperbolic function](http://www.gcseguide.co.uk/functi10.gif)How would I find the vertical and horizontal asymptotes of a $y = \frac{1}{x}$ function algebraically? 
For example, $y = -\frac{2}{x+3}-1$ (as you would type into a calculator). Simply, how do I find the x and y values by looking at this equation?
In other words, the middle point where the asymptotes in the picture has moved and the whole graph has been vertically stretched, where are the asymptotes now?

Comment: Pic if you dont want to use calculus.

Comment: @Marvis, don't you think your edit has changed the meaning of the question?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Am sorry. I understand now. I have now reverted it to the old state.

Comment: Caroline, Marvis took the trouble to edit your question into decent shape. Why did you muck it up? "as you would type into a calculator" is no help at all, as different calculators use different versions of the syntax. Do you, or don't you, want $y={-2\over{x+3}}-1$? If not, and if you can't figure out how to do TeX, can you write out what you mean in words?

Comment: Caroline, what don't you understand about the answers Peter and I have posted? You can edit your question over and over again, but at some point you have to engage with the people who are trying to help you, and let them know what you do, and what you don't, understand.

Answer (score 2):

Not all that different from [Gerry Myerson's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/145283/72), but expanding the explanation of the transformations and including graphs.

---

[image: graph]
basic (parent) graph, $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$; asymptotes: $y=0$, $x=0$

---

[image: graph]
scale by 2 in the $y$ direction ($y\to2y$), $y=\dfrac{2}{x}$; asymptotes: $y=0$, $x=0$

---

[image: graph]
reflect over the $x$-axis ($y\to-y$), $y=-\dfrac{2}{x}$; asymptotes: $y=0$, $x=0$

---

[image: graph]
translate left 3 ($x\to x-3$), $y=-\dfrac{2}{x+3}$; asymptotes: $y=0$, $x=-3$

---

[image: graph]
translate down 1 ($y\to y-1$), $y=-\dfrac{2}{x+3}-1$; asymptotes: $y=-1$, $x=-3$

Comment: Your pictures are worth my thousand words.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that's $y=-{2\over x+3}-1$. There's a vertical asymptote where the function is undefined, and the function is undefined where it involves division by zero. For the horizontal asymptote, you have to ask yourself, what happens when $x$ grows without bound? when $x$ gets very large negative?

EDIT: Reading OP's comments and revised question, I think maybe this approach will be more what's wanted.

I take it you know that for $y=1/x$ the horizontal asymptote is $y=0$ and the vertical asymptote is $x=0$, and they meet at the point $(0,0)$. $y=1/(x+3)$ is the same graph but shifted 3 units to the left; that doesn't change the horizontal asymptote, but it shifts the vertical asymptote to $x=-3$. $y=-1/(x+3)$ flips (or, reflects) the graph in the $x$-axis, but has no effect on the asymptotes, which remain $y=0$ and $x=-3$. $y=-2/(x+3)$ stretches the graph, but again has no effect on the asymptotes. Finally, $y={-2\over x+3}-1$ lowers the graph by 1, so it changes the horizontal asymptote to $y=-1$, while not affecting the vertical asymptote.

So, the new asymptotes are $y=-1$ and $x=-3$, which meet at the point $(-3,-1)$, which is what you are calling the middle point.

Comment: Ok, but if it is parametriced? asymptotes not implies indefinition

Comment: @GastónBurrull, I'm not sure what you are getting at. Can you illustrate with an example?

Comment: You must do a certain rotation before. Asymptotes can be in any direction.

Comment: @GastónBurrull, the question asked about "a $y=1/x$ function". If you have something else in mind, please spell it out. Enough with the cryptic comments.

Comment: No, title says "a Hyperbolic Function", he just shows an example.

Comment: @GastónBurrull, chances are Caroline is a she. Anyway, if Caroline wants to make the question more precise, or more general, she can edit it.

Comment: Sorry I didnt see her name.

Comment: y=1/x is the basic hyperbolic function (according to Algebra teacher)...anything added to that equation is a transformation that I already know how to identify, as in this case, as an x-axis reflection, vertical stretch factor of 2, left 3 and up 1.

Comment: stick to the basics, i am trying to do. big words lead to frustration, frustration leads to math phobia, math phobia....leads to suffering (a totally unhelpful Yoda description of what my parents will do to me with a failing grade)

Answer (score 0):

In general, a homographic function is $$y= \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$

where $c \neq 0$, has two asymptotes.

1. **Horizontal asypmptote**: $$y_h=\frac{a}{c}$$
2. **Vertical asypmptote**: $$x_v=-\frac{d}{c}$$

The canonic form of an homographic function is

$$y=\frac{a}{x+b}+c$$

where $a\neq 0$. Put this way, the asymptotes are $y_h=c$ and $x_v=-b$.

Analytically, we can prove this by using limits, as $x \to -b$ and $x \to \infty$.

---

If one is to generalize to any hyperbola, we use the defining equation:

$$\frac{(x-k)^2}{b^2}-\frac{(y-h)^2}{a^2}=1$$

Then the asymptotes are precisely

$$y_1 = \frac{a}{b}(x-k)+h $$
$$y_2 = -\frac{a}{b}(x-k)+h $$

If it is the case the hyperbola is the conjugate

$$\frac{(y-h)^2}{a^2}-\frac{(x-k)^2}{b^2}=1$$

the asymptotes are (clearly) the same.

Comment: I'd write the vertical asymptote as $x_v$ rather than $y_v$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson True. Fixing.